# QT Pass a slot as parameter as callback

Tags: c++, qt, callback, signals, slot

I am quite new to C++/Qt and experiencing some problems while writing an application that uses a SerialBus-connection connected to multiple other devices.

For communication I wrote a class that wraps QtSerialBus and does some encoding/checksum calculation, etc. This class should be usable by different other classes/threads/modules in my program.

This wrapper class looks simplified like this:

Header:

```
class PeripherieCommunicator : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit PeripherieCommunicator(std::shared_ptr<MultiMasterCommunicator> mmcom, QObject *parent = nullptr);
~PeripherieCommunicator();
private:
std::shared_ptr<MultiMasterCommunicator> mmcom;

template<typename T1> void send(unsigned char command, unsigned char destAddress, T1 sendItem = nullptr) {
    auto sendBuffer = QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&sendItem), sizeof(T1));
    emit sendCommand(command, destAddress, sendBuffer);
}

signals:
    void sendCommand(unsigned char command, unsigned char destAddress, QByteArray sendBuffer = nullptr);
    void openPort();

public slots:
  void CardTypeAGetFullDeviceInfo(unsigned char ucAddress);
  void CardTypeBStartPositioning(unsigned char ucMotorNbr, signed long slPosition, signed long slSpeed, signed long slAcceleration, unsigned char ucAddress);
signals:
    void CardTypeAFullDeviceInfoReceived(CARDA_FULL_DEVICE_INFO strFullDeviceInfo);
    void CardTypeBStartPositioningReceived(unsigned short usCMDAnswer);
    };
```

Example Definition of slot:

```
void PeripherieCommunicator::PR112StartPositioning(unsigned char ucMotorNbr, 
signed long slPosition, signed long slSpeed, signed long slAcceleration, 
unsigned char ucAddress)
{
    CARDTYPEA_START_POSITIONING data;
    data.usMotorNumber = ucMotorNbr;
    data.slDestinationPosition = slPosition;
    data.slSpeed = slSpeed;
    data.slAcceleration = slAcceleration;
    send(COMMAND_START_POSITIONING , ucAddress, data);
}
```

This works fine so far meaning that the commands are being sent via SerialBus and executed. However most of the devices on the bus will send Replies that I need to handle. 
What I tried so far is that I connected a lamba-function in before sending the command that will handle the reply and emitting the corresponding signal. But that would be lead to the situation that every slot that is being connected to that signal is being called. 
What I instead want to achieve is some kind of callback-functionality. Meaning that for example the slot "CardTypeAGetFullDeviceInfo" gets an additional parameter which is the callback slot.
Is there any recommended way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I think, that this could be solved in some other way. Could you please explain what should happen step by step - from sending the message and receiving the answer from the devices, to the processing of the answer and the undertaking of a particullar action.

Comment: I used BlockingQueuedConnection now for that purpose since I would wait for the return anyway